# How to expose types returned by API in typescript

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I am creating a typescript library that can call web services and return data. It provides an API to call the different web services. Each API call returns data of a certain type. In my main module, I export the API.

I can't figure out the best way to expose the types returned by the API. Given that the types have sub-types and so on, there at least 100 types. For readability and abstraction I put them in multiple files.

I thought I could put all the types in the same namespace and then just expose the namespace. I couldn't figure out how to export a single namespace though in typescript. This lead me to believe there is a different way to tackle this problem but I'm not sure what.

**Example:**

```js
// api.ts
export function getData(): IData;
export function getData2(): IData2;
```

```js
// IData1.ts
export interface IData1 {
    subData: ISubData1;
}

export interface ISubData1: {
    value: string;
}
```

```js
// IData2.ts
export interface IData2 {
    subData: ISubData2;
}

export interface ISubData2: {
    subSubData: ISubSubData2;
}

export interface ISubSubData2 {
    value: string;
}
```

```js
// index.ts
import * as api from "./api";
export {api};

// What is the best way to export the type interfaces so that the consumer of this library has type checking?
```

Comment: If this is meant to be used as a library (e.g. compiled JavaScript vs. directly importing the typescript source), you can generate `.d.ts` files that contain the type information. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just export everything from each file in your `index.ts`, like this:

```
export * from './api.ts';
export * from './IData1.ts';
export * from './IData2.ts';
```

If you plan on distributing this through `npm`, be sure to generate and include your declaration files (`.d.ts`) in the distribution. As well as set the `types` field in your `package.json`. [More on that here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html).

Also, you have `expose` in your `api.ts` snippet here, that should be `export` I'm assuming. :P

Comment: That is the route I've currently taken. Since I have potentially hundreds of types, I was hoping to find a more succinct way of exporting. That is why I tried to put all the types in a namespace but I didn't see a way to just export a namespace that spanned multiple files. Thanks for the type correction :)